# Android - Google Analytics V4 on FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics, android-manifest, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to implement Google Analytics V4 in Android. I tried following Google [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), also I tried following this [tutorial](https://benwilcock.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android/). My MainActivity extents FragmentActivity, I have added the GA lib, xml config files and made the modifications showed in the tutorial.

My problem is in the following line that shows me "Cannot resolve 'AnalyticsSampleApp' symbol" error.

```
  Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

I know that I have to change 'MyApplication' and use my own application class name, but how can I find my application class name? How can I register my application class name in my manifest file so I can use it?

I tried this..

```
     ...
<application
    android:name="my.package.myApplication" //Cannot resolve symbol 'myApplication'
     ...
```

Should I implement Google Analytics API in another way since my activity is extending FragmentActivity?

*Sorry if this is a silly question. I am very inexperienced in Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cannot resolve 'AnalyticsSampleApp' symbol"

Because `AnalyticsSampleApp` you have not created AnalyticsSampleApp class in your application.

Create a class with `MyApplication` name and extend `Application` class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public MyApplication() {
   super();
  }
  .....
}
```

Declare `MyApplication` in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="my.package.MyApplication"
 ....
 />
```

Now use `MyApplication` class name instead of  to get `Tracker` instance:

```
Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
                             .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

As provided tutorial link you can follow [MyApplication](https://benwilcock.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android/) class code to create and initialize `GoogleAnalytics` class instace.